# Импорт модуля noty js v2

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Не могу понять как правильно импортировать модуль?

Сейчас вот так:

```
import noty from 'noty'


window.mindy = {
    notify: (text, type = 'success') => {
        noty({
            text: text,
            type: type,
            theme: 'metroui',
            layout: 'topRight',
            timeout: false,
            progressBar: false,
            closeWith: ['click'],
            animation: {
                open: { height: 'toggle' },
                close: { height: 'toggle' },
                easing: 'swing',
                speed: 300,
            },
        })
    },
}
```

Но выдаёт ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

noty.js:2349

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!
(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call 
a class as a function"); } }
```

noty.js:2359

```
_classCallCheck(this, Noty)
```

Comment: А что находится в строчках noty.js:2359 и noty.js:2349?

Comment: @PavelMayorov сейчас дополню сам вопрос скринами

Comment: Не надо скринов! Только текст.

Comment: @PavelMayorov   2359    _classCallCheck(this, Noty);

Comment: @PavelMayorov 2349 function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

Comment: Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" и дополните вопрос. В комментарии код тяжело читается.

Comment: @PavelMayorov отредактировал.

Comment: `import Noty from 'noty'; ... new Noty(...) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `noty.js` выдает что вы используете третью версию noty, а не вторую (вторая версия находится в файле `jquery.noty.js` или `jquery.noty.packaged.js`)

В третьей версии Noty - это класс, а не функция, и вызывать его надо как `new Noty(...)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. 
Как раз тоже задумался а правильной ли версии документацию я читаю